# Trigonometric equation simplification and solution for $θ$.

Tags: trigonometry

For the following trigonometric equation:

$$25\cos2θ = 17\cosθ - 11\sinθ$$

the computer software simplified it as [*in the following link*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25+cos%282x%29+%3D+17+cos%28x%29+-+11+sin%28x%29+):

See the exact form if you scroll down a bit for the solutions section.

Do you have any idea as to how it came to the form of $\arctan(\frac 13)$?

Using the half angle formulae for $\cosθ$ and $\sinθ$ it does not seem to simplify to anything so simple.

Comment: "computation time excedeed". You should grab an image.

Comment: 1/3, you sure ? not $\theta$/3 ?

Comment: anyway I would use $cos 2\theta = 2 cos^2 -1$ and $ sin = \sqrt{1-cos^2}$, then solve the polynomial in cos.

Comment: I guess you are after a solution for x not a simplification, if so, pls change the post title.

Comment: I am after a simplification in order to be able to get a solution. Once we have the simplification, the solution follows. I have altered the title anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (Fabrice), but you end up with $50cos2θ+11√(1−cos2θ)−17cosθ−25=0$ The method given below avoids the square root term. Or would you simplify this to remove the square root term and then solve?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $z=e^{i\theta}$ we rewrite the equation

$$25\frac{z^2+z^{-2}}2=17\frac{z+z^{-1}}2-11\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i},$$or

$$25z^4-(17+11i)z^3-(17-11i)z+25=0.$$

One of the roots of this polynomial happens to be

$$z=\frac{4+3i}5,$$
corresponding to $\tan(\theta)=\dfrac34$.

Compare to the Wolfram solution

$$\tan\left(2\arctan\left(\frac13\right)\right)=\frac{\dfrac23}{1-\dfrac19}=\dfrac34.$$

The remaining roots can be found using Cardano's formulas.

Comment: Just one query - if the general form of the solution is $z=r(cosθ + isinθ)$, should it be $z = 5(4 + 3i)$, where $z = √ (x^2 + y^2) = √(16 + 9)=√25=5$?.

Comment: @J132: no, the root is such that $r=1$.